# android emulating a reboot

Tags: android

I have coded a BroadcastReceiver to enable the resetting of an alarm if a user has to reboot hid device.   Is there any way to test this in the emulator, in other words what sequence of events are required to cause the emulator to kick off the BroadcastReceiver .
Ron

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it yet, but Dianne Hackborn wrote the following yesterday:

> You can also use "adb shell am" to
>   send a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast to
>   your app for quick testing.  I can't
>   remember the exact syntax, but "am
>   help" will tell you.  Be sure to
>   specific your explicit component name
>   when doing this, or you will cause all
>   installed apps to re-run their boot
>   completed receivers, which may not be
>   fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to do it will be to close the emulation window and start it again. If you are running Eclipse, simply close the emulator and then run/debug your project to start it again.

Comment: Closing the emulation window and starting again passes over a breakpoint in the reboot BroadcastReceiver.  I cam across the following comment:-

Comment: SOLVED!!! It wasn't working because the app was being installed on the SD card, thus missing the BOOT_COMPLETED intent.

Comment: Anyone confirm if this is true?

Comment: I am still struggling with this.  I have a class RestoreOnReboot extends BroadcastReceiver and a breakpoint in this.   From Eclipse I run Debug and the emulator starts up with the my app running.  From the command line I run:-                                                                adb shell am broadcast BOOT_COMPLETED          The command line confirms that the intent was broadcast but the breakpoint is not hit.  Is there a tutorial (for simple minds like mine) on testing with adb and the emulator?